# Log Internal Note with wizard Odoo11

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I am trying to add a feature to require "Log Note", the internal note logged in Vendor bills, upon canceling a bill record. I have created a wizard(popup) with a field that asks me to write a reason for canceling. after that the state of the bill becomes a draft and the reason should be registered in the internal log note. my code below

```
    def cancel_reason_bill(self):
         self.env['account.invoice'].browse(self._context.get("active_ids")).update({'reason': 
         self.reason})
         return self.env['account.invoice'].browse(self._context.get("active_ids")).write({'state': 
         'draft'})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add log notes in form view, read [Mixins](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/mixins.html) details here.

1. ```
    class BusinessTrip(models.Model):
        _name = 'business.trip'
        _inherit = ['mail.thread']
        _description = 'Business Trip'

        name = fields.Char()
        partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', 'Responsible')
        guest_ids = fields.Many2many('res.partner', 'Participants')
   ```
2. add chatter in your form view.
3. Inherit message note xml template of vendor bill and add reason.